# How to get the depth data from kinect and visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, kinect-sdk

Hey guys I am stuck in the final year project. My prof has asked me to find the depth od a real time image using kinect and Visual studio. I have no idea about it as I am not a software guy. Any help regarding the coding will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have to use visual studio, then I suggest getting XNA.. Its a games library with a lot of quality tutorials.

A simple google search and I see a relevant article!

http://kinectxna.blogspot.ca/2012/02/tutorial-4-depth-stream.html

Good luck with your project!